# Method is not defined error

Tags: meteor

I am trying to implement some private methods that cannot be called from the client, by defining them outside of the Meteor.methods scope, and under the server folder

I have this

```
Meteor.methods

    #
    # Generates a random event based on tags
    #
    generateRandomEventForCharacter: (characterId) ->
        character = Characters.findOne(characterId)
        rarity = randomRarity()

        # Tags
        locationTags  = ['all', character.location]
        alignmentTags = character.alignmentTags
        characterTags = character.characterTags

        event = Events.findOne( $and: [
            locationTags:  { $all: locationTags },
            alignmentTags: { $all: alignmentTags },
            characterTags: { $all: characterTags }
        ])

        return event

#
# Random rarity
#
randomRarity: () ->
    random = Math.random()

    rarity = switch
        when random < 0.005 then 'mythical'
        when random < 0.050 then 'epic'
        when random < 0.100 then 'rare'
        when random < 0.250 then 'uncommon'
        else 'common'
```

But somehow the following exception is thrown

```
Exception while invoking method 'generateRandomEventForCharacter' ReferenceError: randomRarity is not defined
```

Comment: I assume that both these functions are defined in the same file, right? If not, please remember that Meteor is scoping local variables to the file which they're defined in.

Comment: Jep, in the same file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`randomRarity:` should be `randomRarity =`. Did the same mistake some days ago :)